# List Iterator next element of an element

Tags: java

I'm working with a big set of data and using lists. 
I'm using list iterators to run through the linked list, so i came across a problem, i have to get the next element of next element. 
i dont want to get so high specially working with a set with 28k data.

So, using list iterator, theres a way to get the next element of next?

like this:

```
ListIterator<type> ITERATOR = mylist.listIterator()
while(ITERATOR.hasnext()){
  ITERATOR.next().next()??
}
```

Comment: Call `ITERATOR.next()` twice (if there is a second element).

Comment: This is dangerous, you're open to have a `NoSuchElementException` by calling `next()` twice without checking `hasNext` before.

Comment: How does the title matches your real question?

Comment: sorry @TOM i was writing this tittle before i search for it :), let me correct.

Comment: You can't do that with iterators. Iterators are meant to go through each element once and do something with that element. You'll have to use a `for` loop.

Comment: Well you can't do iterator.next().next() because iterator.next() gives you Object and not Iterator. What you can do is call iterator.next() twice if you are absolutely sure that it will never happen that the list has less than 2 elements. But as a standard practice always check for Iterator.hasnext()

Comment: (a) Please follow code conventions - identifiers in ALL CAPS are used for constants. Variable names should start with a lowercase letter, and continue with lowercase letters except word beginnings: `iterator`, `myList`, etc. (b) Can you explain *why* you need next of next? Sometimes there are other solutions.

Comment: @RealSkeptic i'm adapting a code that uses 2 fors (it gives me heap space overflow, and n^2). In this case i need to something with element(k) and element(k+1).

Comment: Then how about saving the *previous* element in a variable? At the end of each iteration, put the element in the `previous` variable. At the beginning, check if `previous` is not null, and if so, do whatever you need with `previous` and the current element?

Comment: @RealSkeptic uhm...it think it will work too. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every loop of the while will give you 2 objects and they will change each loop.

```
ListIterator<type> ITERATOR = mylist.listIterator()
while(ITERATOR.hasnext()){
      Object first= ITERATOR.next();
       if(ITERATOR.hasNext())
          Object second= ITERATOR.next();

}
```

Comment: Note that this will give you for the first iteration, elements 0 and 1, the second iteration, elements 2 and 3, then elements 4 and 5 and so on. If one wishes to work on 0 and 1, 1 and 2, 2 and 3, this won't do.